# finite cyclic simple groups can be generated by two elements

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

With reference to  [Peter Clark](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements/59300#59300)
answer here, 
I have the following question ( I think it is not difficult but I am not able to see how it can be done )

> He says most finite simple groups can be generated by two elements
>   $G=<x,y>$ where $x$ has order 2 and $y$ has order 3.

Suppose I take $G=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is a prime, I am not able to see how as every non trivial element has order $p$.

May be by "most finite simple groups " he mean non Abelian simple groups.Kindly correct me If I have made some mistake.

**Edit :**

I want to study this result,If somebody know the reference Kindly mention it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: He's definitely talking about the non-abelian groups.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The cases where the simple group can be generated by even one element are considered to be "trivial".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sir from where I can read about the result that most finite simple group can be generated by two elements where one has order 2 and other has order three.

Comment: There is a "most" in the statement as there is a series of finite simple non-abelian groups whose order is *not* divisible by $3$ (Suzuki groups, not *the* sporadic Suzuki group).